# ACCESS 2010 / SQL: How do you copy a row which has an attachment field?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to run a SQL query to copy a row from my table to either the same table or another table.

Whichever method I use, I end up with a message telling me something similar to "You can't run an INSERT INTO query if it contains a multi-value field" (translated from french)
I tried using SELECT * INTO, but the result is the same.

My table is about reports, which can have a revision (hence the row copy), and they can have an attachment like for ex. a pdf file.

so, how do you / can you copy a row which has an attachment field ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have Access 2010 to hand at the moment, but you will find that attachments are stored in hidden system tables as single records and that you need to use that table to copy multiple records, unless you wish to use VBA.

More info: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/guide-to-multivalued-fields-HA001233722.aspx?pid=CH100645681033
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb258184.aspx

Comment: so basically I need to write something to copy the data from the hidden table. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: You should also probably stop using multi-value fields. The only reason they were introduced into A2007 was for compatibility with Sharepoint and if you're savvy enough to program or to write your own SQL, you really should be setting up your on many-to-many join tables instead of relying on this hard-to-use feature.

Comment: @GoldBishop David W Fenton, now sadly deceased, was for many years an MS Access MVP. It is unlikely that he would have commented without just cause. I have seen many posts where multivalue fields have tied users in knots.

Comment: @Remou yeah....fell into that trap once....got out of it by learning and studying the concept of Join Tables and how to Properly implement them.